# ION iCade with Mame on a PC

Tags: mame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iCade bluetooth keyboard mappings for MAME?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24774/icade-bluetooth-keyboard-mappings-for-mame)

I'm trying to play Mame Games on my PC with my ION iCade Joystick.

- My PC recognizes the ION iCade.
- I deactivated UAC under Windows 7.
- I installed [this iCade script](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/25345/23) with AutoHotKey.
- I installed [this icade.cfg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/25345/23) in "ctrlr" mame directory.

When I'm under Windows, the iCade UP moves up, and the icade DOWN moves down. But when I'm under mame interface or a mame game it does not work.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! It looks to me like your question is the same as a question that's been asked before on this site, so I've voted to close it as a duplicate. I would encourage you to look at the question in Jupotter's comment to see if the answers there resolve your issue; if not, by earning a little reputation, you can comment on the best answer and ask if they can clarify something for you.

Comment: Yes i know, but i asked my question in this topic this morning and a moderator deleted it... So i created a new topic... I don't know how to have some help.

Comment: The right thing to do is to link the other question from your own question and explain exactly why your question is different, and specifically why the answers on the other question do not address your problem. Just edit this question (small edit link underneath ut) to add the explanation. Please never respond to another question with your own question.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting either `SendMode` line?