# Does JOYSTICK-IT work with MAME on PC?

Tags: pc, hardware, mame

I'm thinking of getting a [JOYSTICK-IT](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/e75a/) by ThinkGeek, the guys who developed the iCade. However, **I would like to know if the Joystick works for a MAME Emulator on PC.**

It should be able to connect fine, since it is Bluetooth based, however I have doubts because of the iCade's incompatibility with PC (Discussed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24774/icade-bluetooth-keyboard-mappings-for-mame)).

Does anyone have experience with the Joystick? Or can anyone tell me if it would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JOYSTICK-IT does not contain any electronics, but works by mimicking a human finger and this registers as a press on the screen.
This product will not work with a PC unless you could get input from a touch input device to register the presses and map them to key presses.

Answer (score 2):

The JOYSTICK-IT isn't an electrical product, it doesn't connect to the device by bluetooth or any other type of connection, it is simply a small stick with a conductive base that works when placed on a touch screen where the "virtual thumb stick" usually is.

For that reason I doubt there'd be ***any*** way for you to use this with your PC, unless you have a tablet PC or use it on a touchpad.